# WordPress - How to know if a sidebar is empty without loading it?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to wrap the sidebar by a DIV, and if the sidebar is empty the DIV should not be displayed

But i cannot use codes like

```
if(dynamic_sidebar(1))
{
  echo '<div>';
  dynamic_sidebar(1);
  echo '</div>';
}
```

as it will load the sidebar before the DIV if it is not empty, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use output buffering. When output buffering is on, anything which would normally be echoed to the screen is instead stored in a buffer. You can then test to see if there is anything in the buffer before outputting your div tags.

```
ob_start();
dynamic_sidebar(1);
$sidebar = ob_get_clean();  // get the contents of the buffer and turn it off.
if ($sidebar) {
    echo "<div>" . $sidebar . "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
if ( is_active_sidebar(1) )
{
  echo '<div>';
  dynamic_sidebar(1);
  echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the WordPress [is_dynamic_sidebar()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_dynamic_sidebar); function.

It returns `true` if any registered sidebar contains a widget; otherwise false.

**Example:**

```
<?php if(is_active_sidebar('my-sidebar') ) { ?>

<div class="about-us">

    <?php dynamic_sidebar('my-sidebar'); ?>

</div>

<?php } ?>
```

This is the widget-area/sidebar register script I run from the `functions.php`:

```
function foxinni_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
      'name' => 'My Sidebar',
      'id' => 'my-sidebar',
      'description'   => '','before_widget' => '','after_widget'  => '','before_title'  => '','after_title'   => '',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'foxinni_widgets_init' );
```

Notice that I use the string, `my-sidebar`, to identify the sidebar by id.